# Is it possible to create a single EXE of my system?

Tags: windows, installation, php, automation, postgresql

I have made an advanced and complex library/framework in PHP. Currently, if I wanted to put this on a new computer, I would have to perform (in broad terms) these manual steps:

1. Install PHP CLI.
2. Install PostgreSQL.

(Already these two steps are highly involved with tons of fiddling, unthinkable to have somebody else do who isn't already some sort of expert.)

3. Unzip my library and application code to some dir.
4. Configure all of this according to detailed instructions.
5. Finally locate and run a specific script to start up the "engine", meaning my master loop PHP CLI script.

I can do this myself, but I would never in a million years expect anyone else to get this right. I'd love for them to just have to "install" a single, self-contained EXE which immediately starts up my master loop PHP CLI script by somehow embedding both PHP and PostgreSQL and everything set up just to make it dead-simple for the user to run it with zero configuration. Security updates are a major issue, of course, so I'd probably frequently re-distribute this single EXE, or even have the system auto-update itself by fetching it and reloading itself.

But how would this be done in practice, if it's even possible at all? I can see at least two major problems:

1. PostgreSQL has no "embedded mode". I and others have requested this for years, but they seem unwilling to do it. SQLite does, but is so crippled and different from PG that I'd have to entirely redesign my entire system, which is not an option. It was made for PostgreSQL as a core component from the ground up.
2. I am aware of the existence of Docker, and suspect that it will be mentioned/suggested, but even though I consider myself a "power user" and "programmer" (I'd *better* be, having spent most of my life in front of this machine...), I just cannot seem to understand how to actually use Docker to do anything. It's like my brain is incompatible with that software or something. I feel the same about Blender and Unity. But not about other complex software. I can't explain it.

Is this just yet another of those things that are "just not gonna happen"? Or is there some simple, nice way to accomplish this?

I don't have any money to spend on this.

Answer (score -1):

You can install this relatively simply, by zipping the following things:

Installers of each program
Folders required

Than you add a script to run each step. The problem is, that you cannot just copy a path of services, since they are not just running from one folder, likely many registry keys - many could depend on user set variables, which might be different on other operating systems.

If you need to do this dozens, even thousands of times, just create a clean Operating system install and get just this setup working, than clone the HDD Image to other hdds. Only need to activate windows than and it should work.

For linux, this should be much simpler. It should not care much, what machine the drive is in and that 20 other identical installs are running in the neightbor server rack.

As for just the package you desire, this is bad luck. But if you want to install this on thousands of servers or so, cloning the clean os with this configuration set up after the install, this would safe a lot of time and effort. It could be semi automated even.

If your system is clean enough of other data, you could just clone it as is (if linux) - for windows there sure needs to be an activation wizard.